# Qt portable project folder

Tags: qt, project, portability, visual-studio-2010

so i m trying to setup a movable folder for a Qt project where I 'll have this structure and everything will be dependent ONLY with that content..

1. project\

   - script.dat          *"script to invoke qmake with just a click"*
   - qmake.exe
   - moc.exe
   - mkspec\            *"win32-msvc2010" copy*
   - common\            *"necessary by qmake" copy*
   - project.pro
   - sources\

     - main.cpp
     - etc...
   - headers\

     - etc...
   - depedencies\

     - Qt\

       - include\
       - lib\
       - dll\
     - e.g.Boost\

       - include\
       - lib\
       - dll\

as can be seen i want a decent folder structure where the script will append the path to the dlls and set QMAKESPEC etc with respect to the %cd% (*PWD*) directory of the .pro file...

However the problem arises when i invoke qmake.exe

> > C:\Users\ardit\Desktop\test>qmake -v

QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.1 in C:\build-essential\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2010_opengl\lib

and after that

> > qmake -tp vc

creates a project that has everything linked to my Qt installation and NOT the folder specified in the pro

> > visual studio additional include directories:

"include";".";"........\build-essential\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2010_opengl\include";"........\build-essential\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtGui";"........\build-essential\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtCore";"debug";........\build-essential\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2010_opengl\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

I havent put the Qt installation in the Path, but still the qmake.exe knows it somewhow (registry perhaps?)...

example .pro file where include\ has copy of Qt5\include\ , lib\ and dll\ as well

```
TARGET= test

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
        glwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
        glwindow.h

INCLUDEPATH=$${PWD}\include $$PWD
DEPENDPATH=$${PWD}\include $$PWD


LIBPATH=$${PWD}\lib

LIBS+=-L$$LIBPATH -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets
```

Sidenote: I m new here so plz dont bash me...

any help appreciated...

Comment: `I havent put the Qt installation in the Path, but still the qmake.exe knows it somewhow (registry perhaps?)...` -> No, it will get that information from the location of qmake. You should _really_ not import that into your project. That is a very very bad idea. But in general, this project structure does not make sense IMHO because of importing everything. It is better to use the system-wide installation. Thereby, the main question is: why don't you do that?

Comment: if i invoke qmake from arbitrary folder it is NOT known, if i do so from the project's folder it says the above message wherever the project is located...

I want to distribute my project this way   to my professor whom i cannot assume has a Qt installation working...
i 'll only link the required libs and dlls...

So i ll preferably create the project by hand ,compose in Qt Creator  and distribute the msvc project...

Comment: Still, you would not need qmake, moc, and the include files on the build machine which I suppose to be yours. Furthermore, you could still use the system-wide installation on your machine, and ship the necessary qt dlls along with your software. I still suggest to reduce this complex layout to the normal layout people use out there. If you want your professor to build your software, well, just give him the Qt installer, and he can click next/next/next. :)

Comment: Unfortunately Qt binary builds are not portable. If you just move entire Qt installation to another directory, it stops working. So you can't include Qt itself in the project.

Comment: well, it's possible that i just link the libraries to a visual studio project but then i cant use MOC stuff like signals/slots and few other things... thnx anyway ... :)
Pavel Strakhov, i suppose i hit a dead end with movable qmake.exe :(